# Staggered difference-in-difference for binary outcome and time-to-outcome

Tags: paneldata, stata, r, difference-in-difference, causality

I am trying to find out the effect of a training program for employees by answering 2 questions:

1. Does taking training increase the probability of an employee getting promoted?
2. Does taking training reduce the time taken for a promotion (if it happens)?

We also know the following:

- Employees can join/leave the company at any time
- Employees can choose to take the training at any time after joining and before leaving the company
- There are observed time-varying covariates that we would like to control for as they affect promotion probability/time (e.g. employee in a technical/non-technical role, employee's organization/team)
- We have panel data on the above
- There are unobserved confounders (e.g. motivation, intelligence)

As examples, these are likely situations for 4 employees:

- Employee 1 joins company at period 1, and leaves at period 3 without taking training and without getting promoted
- Employee 2 joins company at period 5, and does not take training, get promoted or leave the company (as of today)
- Employee 3 joins company at period 12, takes training at period 20, gets promoted at period 30, and does not leave the company (as of today)
- Employee 4 joins company at period 1, takes training at period 1, gets promoted at period 7, leaves company at period 10

These are simplifications I have in mind (hopefully these actually make the questions above easier to answer, not harder):

- For question 1 above, "taking training" as a binary treatment, and "getting promoted" as a binary outcome.
- Take only the first training and promotion per employee (if they happen). Once an employee takes training, they remain treated. Once an employee gets promoted, they remain promoted.
- Only considering employees that do not have changes to their covariates (so time-varying covariates become time-invariant)

I don't seem to find staggered difference-in-difference articles on binary outcomes or time-to-outcomes. Leaning towards easy-to-use methods rather than very precise estimates.

- Any advice on what papers/methods/packages address these problems?
- Are there better/other simplifications to get quick and reasonable estimates?
- How can I set up my data to answer question 2 (time-to-promotion)?